# Chat Firebase Toast Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fa = getView();

    ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container,false);
    layoutToast = (TextView)fa.findViewById(R.id.layoutToast);

    return ll;
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);

    if (!UtilChat.checkConnection(getActivity())){
       UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(),"LOL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

       // finish();
    }else{
        bindViews();
        verificaUsuarioLogado();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
    }
}


public class UtilChat {
public static final String URL_STORAGE_REFERENCE = "gs://korenovskguide-99b08.appspot.com";
public static final String FOLDER_STORAGE_IMG = "image";

public static void initToast(Context c, String message){
    Toast.makeText(c,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public  static boolean checkConnection(Context context) {
    boolean connection;
    ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    connection = conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    return connection;
}
```

Проблема c:

> UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(),"LOL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Ошибка:

> Error:(125, 20) error: method initToast in class UtilChat cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: Context,String found:
>   FragmentActivity,String,int reason: actual and formal argument lists
>   differ in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей ошибке дословно написано, что ожидаются 2 параметра с типами Context и String, а вы передаёте Context, String и int.

Т.е. просто уберите последний аргумент, т.е. так сделайте:

```
UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(), "LOL");
//а не так:
//UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(), "LOL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: Error:(124, 9) error: unreachable statement 
Error:(136, 5) error: missing return statement  Теперь имеются такие ошибки

Comment: @Imperator, вам бы хотя бы первые пару глав любого учебника по Java прочитать прежде чем с Firebase возиться) Перенесите  `return ll;` в конец метода - у вас сейчас метод завершается до дохода до выделенного красным кода. Это ошибка компиляции.